# Wrong order in index

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, makeindex

I'm getting an unplesant result with `makeindex`:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,twoside,parskip=half]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 

\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=Register,options={-g lp3.ist},options={-s lp3.ist}]

\begin{document}

This is a short Test.

\index{apple}
\index{Number}
\index{$\alpha$}
\index{7}
\index{7 the Borg}
\index{seven the Borg}
\index{soeven@söven}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

and lp3.ist:

```
quote '+'
headings_flag 1
symhead_positive "Symbols"
numhead_positive "Numbers"
heading_prefix "{\\textbf "
heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak%\n \\indexspace\\nopagebreak%"
delim_0 "\\dotfill "
delim_1 "\\dotfill "
delim_2 "\\dotfill "
delim_r "~--~"
suffix_2p "\\,f"
suffix_3p "\\,ff"
preamble
"\\markright{INDEX}\n\n\\begin{theindex}\n\\thispagestyle{headings}\n"
postamble "\n\n\\end{theindex}\n"
```

[image]

I'm expecting **7 the Borg** to be itemized under Numbers but **not** under Symbols. How can I achive that?

**Addendum:** I'm open for any solution as long as I get a correct, punctilious Index.

Comment: `\index{7@7 the Borg}`

Comment: @egreg, works fine, but not with `\index{7 the Boerg@7 the Börg}` any idea why?

Comment: From the makeindex manual (emphasis by me): »A special symbol is defined here to be any character not appearing in the union of digits and the English alphabetic characters. Patterns starting with special symbols precede numbers, which precede patterns starting with letters. *As a special case, a string starting with a digit but mixed with non-digits is considered to be a pattern starting with a special character*.«

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an item categorized under numbers, it should consist only of digits. As specified by the rules, if the index term is of the form

```
<pre>@<post>
```

the part `<pre>` is used for sorting, so it is this one that must consist of digits only.

Here's a possible way out.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,twoside,parskip=half]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=Register]

\newcommand{\numindex}[2]{%
  \begingroup\edef\y{\pdfescapehex\expandafter{\detokenize{#2}}}%
  \edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\index{#1#1#1\expandafter\converthex\y 00000000\relax @\unexpanded{#1 #2}}%
  }\x
}
\def\converthex#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9\relax{\number"#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8}


\begin{document}

This is a short Test.

\index{apple}
\index{Number}
\index{$\alpha$}
\index{7}
\numindex{7}{the Borg}
\numindex{7}{se Borg}
\numindex{8}{söven}
\index{seven the Borg}
\index{soeven@söven}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]